# std::vector of pointers memory leak in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have a simply question about C++.
I have an object, let's say A, that is something like:

```
class A{
  private:
     int a, b, c;
     std::wstring d, e, f;
  public:
     A();
     A( const A &src );
     A( const enumLikeA eA );
     void operator =( const A &src );
};
```

In another class, A_Handler, I have:

```
// .h
class A_Handler{
  private:
    std::vector<A *> myAs;
  public:
    A_Handler();
};
// .cpp
A_Handler::A_Handler()
{
  A *pAs;
  myAs.reserve( 50 );
}

A_Handler::~A_Handler()
{
  for( int i=0; i<myAs.capacity(); i++ )
    delete myAs[i];
  myAs.clear();
}
```

And finally:

```
class BigUser {
  private:
    A_Handler myHandler;
};
```

Big user actually does nothing with myHandler except for creating it.
Now, I'm using a Visual Studio 2010 MFC dialog project, so, in the main dialog class, I have:

```
class MainDlg {
  private:
    BigUser foo;
}
```

This leads to a memory leak. I've commented backward all the code and the instruction that seems to cause the leak is:

```
A_Handler::A_Handler()
{
  // ...
  myAs.reserve( 50 );
  // ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am i Doing wrong" - Not using smart pointers for one

Comment: I can't see any obvious leak, however : `for( int i=0; i<myAs.capacity(); i++ )` could cause a memory error ! `capacity` is the total size of the underlying array, you want to iterate on `vector::size()` which is the actual number of elements held (or just directly use iterators).

Comment: The leak is elsewhere. `reserve()` wouldn't give you a leak. There is no direct use of `new` anywhere in the code you are showing. Your code is plagued with other errors, but there is no obvious memory *leak*.

Comment: @Moore91 nothing wrong with not using smart pointers.

Comment: your code has undefined behavior, destructor especially

Comment: @Nbr44 I'm deleting the memory pointed by the address in the vector, not the vector location itself, or not? In MFC I would write: CArray<A *, A *> myAs; myAs.SetSize(50); myAs[i] = new A(); and delete myAs[i]; then myAs.RemoveAll(). Is this the same?

Comment: @Nbr44 You pointed me right. That was the problem. Post the answer and I'll vote/accept.

Comment: @Moore91 nothing wrong with not using smart pointers.

Comment: That could not be the problem. `capacity()` is never less than `size()`, so there is no way looping over the former would produce a leak. It would produce undefined behaviour because you would end up deleting stuff you don't own.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, the compiler shows no more memory leaks... probably Visual Studio has a different implementation.

Comment: According to your code, the vector is empty anyway, so there should be no memory leak to fix in the first place.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, the vector was empty because I've commented where I filled it and therefore not reported here in the question because the leak was still there. Moreover if I comment the reserve line I have no leak. I don't know if you're using different enviroments, or getting different behaviours but to be sure I've cleaned and rebuild solution 2 times: no more leaks with Nbr44 correction.

Comment: Get rid of the rule-of-three violation. Clearly, you are using the wrong types. You might want to use `boost::ptr_vector<A>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` instead of `std::vector<A*>` because obviously `A*` does not have the ownership semantics you want. And if you don't need the level of indirection, `std::vector<A>` is even better.

Comment: Don't be that guy who declares his own copy operations and destructors when this is not neccessary if you pick the right types for your class members.

Comment: @sellibitze I don't get your point, but it's obviously because it's my first try with STL, I always use old plain MFC. Anyway, which file includes ptr_vector?

Comment: @Moore91 You're too young to know, but we've have been told for more than a decade that C++ smart pointers (`auto_ptr`) and the C++ Standard Library containers are mutually exclusive. Your comment is incomplete, and incorrect. Using smart pointers is a potential solution, unless you chose the wrong smart pointer.